# Where I can find the Property Pages of a project in VS studio in terms of a file on computer

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-setup

In solution Explorer,
If you right click on a project, at the bottom,

There is an option ----> 'Properties'

My question is,

how do I find the 'Properties' page in terms of a file on computer?

Because I want to compare the properties of different projects....

Thank you very much for the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These project properties are stored in the `<Your Project Name>.csproj` file (for C# projects).

The project file holds also information on the structure of your project as well as the references.